# How to avoid a generics warning

Tags: java, generics

I have a utility function that will shuffle the
elements of any Vector, but which generates generic
warnings about using raw types.

```
static public void shuffle(Random r,Vector v)
   {    int sz = v.size();
        for(int pass = 0;pass<4;pass++)
        {   for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
            { int j=nextInt(r,sz);
              Object ii = v.elementAt(i);
              v.setElementAt(v.elementAt(j),i);
              v.setElementAt(ii,j);
            }
        }
  }
```

there seems to be no way to quiet the warnings other than by
suppressing them.  Changing the method signature to `Vector<Object>`
restricts the callers `Vector<Object>`.  Changing to `Vector<?>` makes
the setElementAt uncompilable.

Comment: critique: it would be better to use `List`: 


1. `Vector` is an older collection, updated to use the favored `List` interface
2. Coding to the interface, rather than the class is more flexible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out already, you can do this with generics like so:

```
public static <T> void privateShuffle(Random r, Vector<T> v) {
    int sz = v.size();
    for (int pass = 0; pass < 4; pass++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            int j=nextInt(r,sz);
            T ii = v.elementAt(i);
            v.setElementAt(v.elementAt(j), i);
            v.setElementAt(ii, j);
        }
    }
}
```

However, since you're writing a utility method I'd prefer the `?` wildcard syntax - it's a lot cleaner to look at. As you've already noted, you can't use the following header directly on that method, but I'd be tempted to do something like the following:

```
public static void shuffle(Random r, Vector<?> v) {
    privateShuffle(r, v);
}

private static <T> void privateShuffle(Random r, Vector<T> v) {
    int sz = v.size();
    for (int pass = 0; pass < 4; pass++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            int j=nextInt(r,sz);
            T ii = v.elementAt(i);
            v.setElementAt(v.elementAt(j), i);
            v.setElementAt(ii, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, it's an extra method, but that way you get to expose the "clean API" look of the unbounded wildcard whilst still maintaining the type safety (this is how a lot of the Java API methods work.)

As a side note, I'd also re-iterate that unless you're doing this for legacy reasons, Vector is generally considered an obsolete collection these days and a much better choice would be to use a list (and code to the list interface.)

Comment: Thanks.  that static <T> syntax is the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

First you should note that you're reinventing the wheel.

[`Collections.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)`(yourVector, yourRandom);`

does the trick :-)

---

To make your method generic for all types of `Vector`s, this is the way to write it:

```
static public <T> void shuffle(Random r, Vector<T> v) {
    int sz = v.size();
    for (int pass = 0; pass < 4; pass++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            int j = nextInt(r, sz);
            T ii = v.elementAt(i);
            v.setElementAt(v.elementAt(j), i);
            v.setElementAt(ii, j);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: It is worth noting that Collections.shuffle results in a uniform distribution over all permutations (assuming Random to be perfectly random), but the home-grown method does not.

Comment: actually, this code has been around so long that collections is reinventing my wheel. but I"m just upgrading the neighborhood to use generics.

Comment: Hehe, ok. If it's legacy code and you can't remove your shuffle routine, and you want a "good shuffle" I still suggest you just implement it as a wrapper call to `Collections.shuffle`.

Comment: Making it a wrapper is a good idea in this particular case.  I'm interested in the general case.  A similar wart is that you can't write Vector<String>[] = new Vector[2]; without a warning to suppress.

Comment: Ah, yes. The trick there is to do a `class StringVector extends Vector<String>` and do `Vector<String>[] = new StringVector[2]` iirc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the supresswarning annotation

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

edit: why doesn't the vector < T > work for you? It should? :)

Comment: that's what I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: The `<?>` attempt results in a `The method setElementAt(capture#3-of ?, int) in the type Vector<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#4-of ?, int)`

Comment: yeah, forgot that you can't pass anything into a ? generic type, just get.

Comment: That's not really *avoiding* the warning, it's just ignoring it!